# Google Adsense rejection for multiple accounts

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense

I applied for Google Adsense when my website was under construction due to my low knowledge of Google Adsense. I got rejected and later realized why I was rejected, I fix everything and reapply but to my biggest, I got rejected for having two accounts, am confused because I don't think having a YouTube channel on the same email should affect the Google ads.

[image: Screenshot of the feedback from Google ads]

I will be glad if anyone has an idea of the way out here. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify in your title and question that it is Adsense that you're having issues with. Google Ads is specifically the platform for purchasing advertising, so your current wording is confusing.

Comment: Clarification has been done, is there anything that could has caused this issue

Comment: Thank you. And no, having other Google products on the same email address is not the same, in fact Google make it almost impossible to do some things if you don't do this. Google can be woolly with their language, but they do differentiate between product account and user account. It sounds like there is another AdSense account associated with your website.

Comment: Am so surprised with this, this is my first time and have not been using any other email than my email am using presently.

Comment: I would contact Google support, they may be able to offer some more advice. It could be that someone else has registered your domain in AdSense (perhaps they previously owned it), it could be a different subfolder of the same domain (I'm not sure what your website address is), and Google believes they are the same website. Support should be able to help you there.

Comment: Have tried all my possible best, am just so confused. My website is Https://libertygist.com.ng